# Get the value after a string and comma and ends if there is character '|'

Tags: java, arrays, string, algorithm

If I have string variable :

```
String word = "wordA";
```

and I have another string variable :

```
String fullText= "wordA,A A|wordB,B B|wordC,C C|wordD,D D";
```

so is it possible to get the value after the comma and ends with `|` ?

**Example**

If word equals `"wordA"` then I get only `"A A"` because in fullText right after wordA and comma is 'A A' and ends with `|`

and if word equals `"wordD"` then varible result is `"D D"` based on the variable fullText.

So how to get this variable result in Java ?

Comment: Give us your current sketch of solution please !

Comment: Look into regular expressions with capturing group.

Comment: i tried couple of ways but still stuck . i have tried all string manipulation but cant find the proper way of getting the expected value. plus if i knew the answer i wouldnt ask btw. thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java8 you can use stream like so :

```
String result = Arrays.stream(fullText.split("\\|")) // split with |
        .filter(s -> s.startsWith(word + ","))       // filter by start with word + ','
        .findFirst()                                 // find first or any
        .map(a -> a.substring(word.length() + 1))    // get every thing after work + ','
        .orElse(null);                               // or else null or any default value
```

Comment: it works, thank you so much for the answer. but if i insert the value for variable word other than that example "worddd" then it will return "A A"

Comment: @user_22 you say that you get `A A` if you pass `worddd` ??

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regular expression. Like this:

```
String text = fullText.replaceAll(".*" + word + ",([^\\|]+).*", "$1");
```

Alternatively:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(word + ",([^\\|]+)").matcher(fullText);
matcher.find();
matcher.group(1); // "A A" for word = wordA
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public static String search(String fullText, String key) {
    Pattern re = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\|)" + key + ",([^|]*)(?:$|\\|)");
    Matcher matcher = re.matcher(fullText);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Example:

```
    String fullText= "wordA,A A|wordB,B B|wordC,C C|wordD,D D";
    System.out.println(search(fullText, "wordA"));
    System.out.println(search(fullText, "wordB"));
    System.out.println(search(fullText, "wordC"));
    System.out.println(search(fullText, "wordD"));
```

Output:

```
A A
B B
C C
D D
```

UPDATE: To avoid recompiling the regex at each search:

```
private static final Pattern RE = Pattern.compile("(?:^|\\|)([^,]*),([^|]*)(?:$|(?=\\|))");

public static String search(String fullText, String key) {
    Matcher matcher = RE.matcher(fullText);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(1).equals(key)) {
            return matcher.group(2);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```